# Как настроить Android App Bundles чтобы опубликовать apk (PWA)?

Tags: java, android, google-play, pwa

Есть сайт с PWA, нужно опубликовать его в Google Play.
Сделал все по статье: https://habr.com/ru/post/439238/

Но при публикации гугл ругается на оптимизацию и предлагает оптимизировать через Android App Bundles

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После прочтения тонны материала, я смог добавить модуль Dynamic Feature Module и включить минификацию, в итоге апк с 2мб похудел до 700кб, но гугл все равно не принимает его.

Подскажите как настроить сборку чтобы гугл одобрил?

Comment: Вы при сборке выбрали пункт "Android App bundle"? Нужно выбрать обычный "APK". Вот: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633580/warning-message-when-review-apk

Comment: гугл хочет чтобы файл был не `.apk` а .`aab`, в таком случае он сам сгенерирует нужного размера apk файл для каждой версии android

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, APK больше нельзя загружать в Google Play?

Comment: @МаксимsaysReinstateMonica я выбирал обычный APK

Comment: Тогда наоборот, попробуйте сгенерировать через пункт `"Android App bundle"`, и загрузить `.aab` файл.

Comment: @МаксимsaysReinstateMonica да все получилось

Comment: @AndreyMihalev вы очень помогли, спасибо!

Comment: @AndreyMihalev если создадите ответ, я отмечу его решением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сборке приложения вам нужно выбрать пункт `Android App Bundle` вместо `APK`

[image: image1]

На выходе у вас должен появиться файл с расширением `.aab` его и нужно добавить в `Play Market`